# how do I use filter-branch to get commits to a particular directory?

Tags: git

My current branch `sandbox` has commits that affects lots of files.

I want to make a new branch, off `develop` which has only the commits of `sandbox` that affect a particular folder.

So, in effect, I want `sandbox-myfolder` to have a log that looks like the output of `log -- myfolder`. (We can assume for simplicity that I've kept my commits small, and that if they touch myfolder, they don't touch anything else, and vice versa.)

It looks like `git filter-branch` is the thing to use, but how?

Comment: You mean you want to cherry-pick the commits that affect a given folder onto a new branch? What is the end result here? I'm not sure you will get what you want.

Comment: If the commits are already on a different branch, interspersed with other commits affecting other parts of the repository, then you can't just create a branch that contains these existing commits affecting this folder. That's now how branches in git work. Instead, you can attach a branch to a particular commit but then it also contains all commits that are the ancestors of that commit, all the way back to the start of the repository history. To truly single out the commits into a new branch, you will have to cherry-pick them onto this new branch, but these will be new commits, copies.

Comment: Yes, I want to cherry-pick the commits, but there are quite a lot of them, so an automatic way of cherry-picking them by the folder they affect.

Comment: And copies of the commits is fine!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used filter-branch so I can't really comment, but I have another idea:

How about getting the commit ids (sha1-s) of commits that actually touched the folder of your interest:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" sources/myfolder-path
```

Then you can create a branch from the initial commit (or maybe from the commit that has created the folder of your interest, it should be the last commit from the list you'll get from the previous command) 
Then you can iterate over this list in a loop and apply cherry-pick one by one (or all at once if you wish) to this branch

You'll end up with the branch that contains only commits to the folder and won't rewrite the history for the whole graph.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b sandbox-myfolder sandbox
git filter-branch -- develop..@ -- path/to/myfolder
git rebase develop
```

This will produce a linear history of the changes, depending on the structure you've got and the structure you want you might need some options on your rebase.